# Using observeSingleEvent/snapshot, how can a line be coded that checks if a user added a child entry to the database within the last 24 hours?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

Using `if (snapshot.exists()){` is easy but how can you modify this to only include snapshots of database entries that were made in the last 24 hours?

///this is how it would look if you were only checking if the user has a snapshot. What you want is to check if the snapshot was made within 24 hours.

```
super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    databaseRef.child("users").child(uid).child("Photos").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if (snapshot.exists()){

            print ("good")            }

        else{

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toVegas", sender: nil)

        }


    })
```

If snapshot method does not work, I was thinking that maybe the way certain websites tell you that you can't post within x minutes can be used in reverse (ie `performSegue` if they haven't posted in x minutes/hours).

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this is to use `ServerValue.timestamp()` when creating your child nodes as an extra parameter, once you've done that you can then compare the timestamp of the retrieved snapshot and make the validation of the 24 hours time lapse you are talking about

This is an example function on how you can modify your writing method to the database to include the timestamp

```
func sendMessage() {
    let data = ["UserName": userName,
                "message" : message,
                "timestamp": ServerValue.timestamp()]

    Database.database().reference().child("Photos").setValue(data)
}
```

then in your observer you can do something like this

```
 databaseRef.child("users")
    .child(uid)
    .child("Photos")
    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    guard let message = snapshot.value as? [String:String] else { return }

    let timestamp = message["timestamp"] as! UInt64
    //TODO - Look up how to convert that value to a date, once you get that done you can compare that date to a constant date of 24hrs and decide what to do next in your code

    if (snapshot.exists()){

        print ("good")            
     }else{

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toVegas", sender: nil)

    }


})
```

Comment: Thanks. Roughly how would creating a parameter for ServerValue.timestamp() look in the code? I assume at the end of the function you'd have databaseRef.child("users").child(userID).child("users").setValue("ServerValue.timestamp()")

Comment: nope, it goes with the parameters of each object, I'm assuming that you have the code for when the user creates a child node in "Photos", and you set some parameters as the url, name, description of said image, in those parameters is where you should add a new one, called timestamp and set its value to ServerValue.timestamp(), that way you will get the exact time that node was created

Comment: @noname87f I edited the answer to add some code samples for clarification

Comment: Thanks. I do have a child node for Photos but is has no parameters. Photos as the child is just Photos: "self.imageDownloadURL".I am trying to get both that URL and others like the timestamp as parameters via [String: Double]?, but the self.imageDownloadURL doesn't all that because it is set to String in the entire code.

Comment: update: I am getting that part fixed as parameters, I think I got it.

Comment: awesome, if you find this helpful make it as the accepted answer please

Comment: will do. I'll get to your part asap. I got it to work with the parameters. Now there is one for timestamp and url. Issue I have now is for the fetching of the Photo, the Url was set to child Photos not parameter URL

Comment: then you need to include that as one more parameter of your object when you send it to the DB, like ["photoUrl": someValue]

Comment: hmm.. I'm don't see a part like that in my code. I have the code that fetches the URL from firebase here in this question I just asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57013836/if-photos-were-fetched-from-firebase-as-a-childphotos-what-needs-to-change-in . Do you know where I should add the parameter reference there?